# How to force nginx to include Content-Length header on HEAD requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, http, nginx

How do you configure nginx to return a valid `Content-Length` header when responding to a HTTP `HEAD` request? Currently my server returns this:

```
curl --head http://example.com/myfile.xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 13:49:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=da2daeaa59809916192f7ac0645d3a3e91471960186; expires=Wed, 23-Aug-17 13:49:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 16:20:26 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: W/"57bb264a-5442b26a"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Method: *
Cache-Control: public
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 9dac40-LHR
X-Cache: MISS from Squid
Via: 1.1 Squid (squid/3.2.14)
```

I *must* send the `Content-Length` header with the response to `HEAD` (if I don't, the service that checks that URL will never see that the file was changed, and will not download the new version). How do you set it up?

Comment: Can you post your ngnix configuration?  All of my servers that use nginx (with pretty basic configurations) return Content-length in a HEAD request.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but nginx probably isn't showing the content-length because of nature of dynamic content generated by Rails's application server. 
You can ask Rails to send that in response header. In your Rails application's `config/application.rb` add the following middleware:

```
config.middleware.use "Rack::ContentLength"
```

This should return the `content-length` header in response.

Comment: Thanks... Though what about when nginx is serving the file directly itself, outside of the Rails request cycle? The file is generated offline in a rake task.

Comment: In that case, I am always getting content-length header in my HEAD request. I requested the public image (served by nginx and not by rails) `curl --head http://myserver.com/images/image.png`.